# I am given $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ need $h(x)$

Tags: calculus

> If $h$ is the function given by
> $$
> h(x) = (f \circ g)(x)
> $$
> where $f(x) = 5x^2 -1 $ and $g(x)=|x|$, then what is $h(x)$?
>
> - $|5x²  -1|$
> - $5x-1$
> - $5 |x|-1$
> - $5x^2 - |x|$
> - $5|x|^2 -1$

I put a screenshot because typing it would be difficult

Comment: What are your own thought about this? What did you try?

Comment: I thought maybe to try the chain rule but I wasn't sure

Comment: Chain rule? There's no differentiation here, you literally just have to plug in the expressions for $f$ and $g$ and you're done.

Comment: Plug what in exactly can you show me

Comment: You can read for example the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition
See the examples there and then come back to this problem.

Comment: Oh is it the first one l 5x^2-1 l

Comment: Be careful! Notice that
$$
(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))
$$
And when $g(x) = |x|$, we have
$$
h(x) = (f \circ g)(x) = f(|x|)
$$
etc ...

Comment: so would it be the fourth one 5x^2- IxI

Comment: I wish I was physically there with you to take your hand and do this exercise with you... Let's try another example. What would be the value of
$$
f(s)
$$
for some real number $s$ ? (Plug it in the expression for $f$ and tell what you get, please).

Comment: the value is s.

Comment: Do you mean to say $f(s) = s$ ? I'm getting frustrated with this ... What I mean is if you change $x$ to $s$ , you get
$$
f(s) = 5s^2 - 1
$$
That's what I meant. The point of this was to demonstrate that actually
$$
f(|x|) = 5 |x|^2 -1
$$
So you **literally just have to replace x by what is in the parenthesis**. I hope it's clear to you now.

Comment: ohhhh I am so sorry I understand now

Comment: The answer to this question is what I wrote last in my comment with the equations. For future references, if you don't want your posts downvoted, please write your own thoughts and efforts related to the problem. You have to answer the question: What did you try and what was the difficulty you encountered?

Comment: Indeed, in general we can simplify $|x|^2 $ to $ x^2$. But for learning purposes, perhaps in this case $5|x|^2 -1$ can be seen as the most clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you've gone through the definitions of function compositions you should be able to answer it.
It's $5|x|²-1$

Answer (score 0):

Since $g(x)=|x|$ and $f(x)=5x^2 -1$, then $f(g(x))=5|x|^2-1$.